# Best Practice for temporary query result storage in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a query that takes a bit of time (it involves some computations and accessing a third-party).  Currently, the user makes an HTTP request to initiate the query (it returns immediately).  GAE puts the task in a queue and executes it.  After execution, the task stores the results in a static object.  The user makes another HTTP request later to retrieve the results.

Is there a best practice way to implement something like this?  Would the results be better stored in the DataStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the task stores the results in a static object

How are you making sure that the subsequent request from same user hits the same instance so that it can access the static object?

A better way to do it would certainly be either storing it in memcache (prone to hit or miss) and/or datastore. Keep in mind, with the new pricing model, datastore operations are going to cost more.

Comment: The results will only be fetched once (and then removed).  So even though it won't use the caching advantage of memcache, I assume that it will still be faster retrieval than datastore.

Comment: Yes, if its used just for once, then there is no point in storing in memcache and gamble. Make sure you are removing those entities from datastore after they have been read by your following request.

Comment: As @kunal points out, since you'll have to store it in the datastore anyway (for reliability), and delete it once it's expired, there's no point storing it in memcache at all.